# How to find an element with respect to another element through selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
<div class="block-inner">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="required form-control" value="" placeholder="Enter your username...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group w_margin">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="required form-control" style="" placeholder="Enter your password...">
    </div>
</div>
```

## Context

My need is to find Username in Web page and automatically has to move to the next element to fill value, and once it finds Password text and has to move to next element to fill password from dictionary. Please help me on this.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://account.genndi.com/login")
element = "//label[contains(text(),'')]" #xpath

dictCredentials = {'Username':'abcdef', 'Password':'123'}
for clas in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(element):
    text = clas.text
    if text in dictCredentials.keys():
        inputbox = #please help here get corresponding input element
        inputbox.send_keys(dictCredentials[text])
```

I know how to send keys directly into text box and it is easy too. But I wish to understand how to do the same operation indirectly with another class element.

Comment: Instead of using `class` names you can use `xpath` of an element, which will be easy to locate

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this let me explain how you are going to do this.

So first you need to get the element of Username. 
You have already done this with:

```
element = driver.findElement(by.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'')]"));
```

What you can also do is, get the parent element directly by saying:

```
element = driver.findElement(by.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Username')]/.."));
```

With the `/..` you are getting the ancestor of the element `label` with text `Username`

Now that you have found the element within which your input is located you can say:

```
inputElement = element.findElement(by.xpath("./input"));
```

This way, within the parent element you found, you are going to look for an input field.

Comment: You are welcome. If you could mark this answer as your solution it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to find the `<label>` tags with text as **Username** and **Password** and move to the next element to fill value you can create a function which will accept the `<label>` tag text and the `text-to-send` as two arguments and fill up the next `<input>` as follows :

```
def fillUp(labelText, inputValue):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[.='" + labelText + "']//following::input[1]").send_keys(inputValue)
```

Now, you can call this function from anywhere within your script as follows :

```
fillUp("Username", "Chandrasekar ")
fillUp("Password", "Subramanian")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use "by_name" locator =)

```
user = {"name": "Alex", "password": 'pass'}
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(user.name)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(user.password)
```

If you really want to find "Username" text in parent element - you have few other options:

First is to find wrapper element, that contains specific text, and search for input in it:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[label[text()='Username']]/input").send_keys("name")
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[label[text()='Password']]/input").send_keys("pass")
```

Or search for element's sibling input:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='Username']/following-sibling::input[1]").send_keys("pass")
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='Password']/following-sibling::input[1]").send_keys("pass")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get it with  this pseudo xpath:

```
//*[@name='username']
```

Then:

```
  //*[@name='password']
```

The "move", you can achieve with your code following this pattern:

- click on the input field
- clear filed
- enter text
- move to the next element
- clear filed
- enter text